# favicons/icons for popular units/browsers/OS

Tags: html, metadata, favicon, ico

I've been using an icon generator, to create favicons/icons for various popular units/browsers/OS, for a website

The result is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="favicon-196x196.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="favicon-160x160.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicon-96x96.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml" />
```

Of course, this seems like a bit over the top. I have never seen ANY site use this many icon variations

I would like the icon to be available on most popular units, so people can also add the website to home-screen etc. (with the icon)

But is all this really necessary, or could I easily trim it down to just a few?

What would happen if I for example only used *one* 152x152 size for apple devices, and skipped the smaller sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I ended up with this solution:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#111111" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile.png" />
```

This page helped some http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/

favicon.png is 96x96

favicon.ico is 48x48 (or 3 variatons in one file)

apple-touch-icon.png is 152x152

mstile.png is 144x144

So, the files are a bit large, but this way I won't need a truckload of versions and files. Also, a 4-8 kb file is not that much for user to download (even on phone), and any device should grab the file and downsize it if needed

Answer (score 1):

totally overkill. For Apple, you only need the following

> ```
> apple-touch-icon.png (57x57 iPhone and iPod touch)
> apple-touch-icon-72x72.png (72x72 iPad 1st and 2nd gen)
> apple-touch-icon-114x114.png (114x114 retina iPhone and iPod touch)
> apple-touch-icon-144x144.png (144x144 retina iPad)
> ```

however, if you miss any of these, the following happens:

> ```
> The icon that is the most appropriate size for the device is used. If no sizes attribute is set, the element’s size defaults to 60 x 60.
> ```

```
  If there is no icon that matches the recommended size for the device, the smallest icon larger than the recommended size is used. If there are no icons larger than the recommended size, the largest icon is used.

  If no icons are specified using a link element, the website root directory is searched for icons with the apple-touch-icon... prefix. For example, if the appropriate icon size for the device is 60 x 60, the system searches for filenames in the following order:

apple-touch-icon-76x76.png

apple-touch-icon.png
```

(extracted from [IOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html))

Thus, you can easily use only 144x144.png and nothing will happen, it goes on you whether your icon design looks nice in small sizes or not, but you can totally use only one size

Comment: Ok. What about the other icons? favicon-196x196.png etc. Who uses them and can I trim that down too?

Comment: I think I'll go just with one <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" /> for Apple devices. They use it and rescale automatically (as I understand it)

Answer (score 1):

**First solution - Files in root directory**

Create:

- `favicon.ico`, as usual, as a 16x16 ICO picture. This is for old versions of IE.
- `apple-touch-icon.png` as a 152x152 PNG picture. This is for all iOS devices and Android Chrome.
- `favicon-196x196.png` as a 196x196 PNG picture. This is for recent desktop browsers (and also Android Chrome, also it favors Apple Touch icons at time of writing).
- `mstile-144x144.png` as a 144x144 PNG picture. For Windows 8 / IE 10 and Windows 8.1 / IE 11.

Place them at the root directory of your web site.

Declare them with:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="/favicon-196x196.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png" />
```

As you guess, the icons will be down-sized when necessary.

Yep, `favicon.ico` is not declared. IE will find it as long as it is in the root of the web site. Same for `browserconfig.xml` in case you use it.

**Alternative solution - Files not in root directory**

Create the same icons as above.

Place them somewhere in your web site, eg. `/path/to/icons`.

Declare them with:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/icons/favicon.ico />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/path/to/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="/path/to/icons/favicon-196x196.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/path/to/icons/mstile-144x144.png" />
```

Comment: Please explain why it should be in the root directory? Some say it should, others say it doesn't need to be. I use absolute paths to a icons/ folder, I assume that is perfectly ok

Comment: Yep, files do not have to be in the root directory. To be honest, there is no strong reasons to do so (you can read this is you are interested in the topic: http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_icons_in_root). I added an alternate solution.

Comment: Your alternative solution and my answer is to me the best way to go. Really no need for 15-20 variations. Let's be stubborn and modern ;)

Comment: But you say "The solution: use RealFaviconGenerator".. this is NOT the solution, and is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (even though ok service), please read my question again. Are you link spamming? o.O

Comment: I just removed the self-promoting link. Someone else tried to remove it, but his edit got rejected before I could approve it.

Comment: Alright, I just removed the first solution. Apparently no one wants an easy, reliable way to support all platforms :)

Comment: I bet some do.. but I think most people want a trimmed down flexible modern solution and not a huge pile of code and files. (your alternative and my answer is better). Tweak your generator output a bit (more simple and direct), then it's very good ;)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I agree, the code is not pretty. I will try to shrink the size of the code in the next few months, yet I know in advance that this will require a lot of testing.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

1) Prepare your icon image in resolution 310x310 and PNG format.

2) go to http://faviconit.com, generate your favicons, download and unzip, copy **all** into some folder in project (in my case *root/favicon/*)

3) then go to http://www.favicon-generator.org/, generate your favicons, download and unzip, then copy only **android-icons** (*android-icon-*.png*) and **manifest.json** into some folder in project (in my case *root/favicon/*)

4) don't forget to change paths in *manifest.json* and *browserconfig.xml*

5) then use in your html head something like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="/favicon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="/favicon/favicon-64.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon/favicon-96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="/favicon/favicon-160.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/favicon/favicon-192.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/favicon-57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon/favicon-60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon/favicon-72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon/favicon-76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon/favicon-114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon/favicon-120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon/favicon-144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon/favicon-152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/favicon-180.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicon/favicon-144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicon/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```